# Is there a way to remove content_security_policy to none with Talisman?

Tags: python, flask, swagger-ui, content-security-policy, flask-restful

I have installed Talisman. I have a flask API. When I add flask_swagger_ui, I get these errors:

```
Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700|Source+Code+Pro:300,600|Titillium+Web:400,600,700' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is used as a fallback.

Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-uiD1ejCBF+BQY4HmKpovbP6UD3MuKGymMj+v0lhBlZs='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-ezdv1bOGcoOD7FKudKN0Y2Mb763O6qVtM8LT2mtanIU='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-b3IrgBVvuKx/Q3tmAi79fnf6AFClibrz/0S5x1ghdGU='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-37t0pGv0l-SZroBKCJkJlA'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-VdD52vbcqq158oxfM7ms2Arg3adoR/MYPlb75qKcZPE='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

Does anybody have the same problem? How did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just set it to `[]`:

```
talisman = Talisman(app, content_security_policy=[])
```

I was asked below if this was "safe", and have more to say on this than can add in a comment, so thought I'd edit my answer to address that.

Content Security Policy (CSP) is a very good additional security benefit - particularly to reduce the impact of Cross Site Scripting vulnerabilities on a site.

However it can be complicated to set up properly, and if not set properly it will stop stuff loading on your site (that's the entire intent of it!).

By default you get no CSP - it is something you need to explicitly add to your server to benefit from it.

However, adding a library like Flask Talisman changes that and gives you a default CSP - and quite a strict one at that be default (basically only load content from your site and don't allow Google Fonts for example, and no inline styles/scripts).

So going from no CSP, to adding Flask's default, to removing Flask's default leaves you exactly where you were in the beginning! You have not worsened your security posture. So in that sense yes it's "safe", in that you haven't weakened your security position. You just haven't improved it, and Flask Talisman adds security options. Presumably you're using Flask Talisman's for its other security features otherwise why install it if you're just gonna turn it all off?) that's still a security improvement. But yes it would be better if you could use CSP too for the best protection it can offer (depending on the exact CSP you set).

Of course if you had a good CSP configured in Flask and it was working find, and then you added some changes and it doesn't work, and you disable the whole CSP rather than alter it to cope with your changes then you ARE reducing your security. But I was assuming from the question that they haven't configured a CSP, and the explicit question in the title was asking how to turn it off.

Should Flask Talisman default a (very strict) CSP? That's a good question. Personally I think yes. It's a security library with the explicit intent to set security headers and CSP is a security header. So to me it should have good defaults, that can then be configured if you aren't ready for that protection yet. An alternative would be to have either no CSP (to make it entirely optional) or a weaker CSP (e.g. to allow `upgrade-insecure-requests` which is a good starter CSP). But I think it's better to have it on by default so people can learn about CSP and then consider setting it properly, or explicitly turning it off if they don't want to do that yet.

Comment: Is it safe to go this way?

Comment: That requires some nuance - so edited my answer to include that detail. Let me know if that is not clear or if you have other questions.